# Trouble dynamically creating elements with JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, dynamic

I'm working on a bootcamp and some guys and I have created a group. We are trying to dynamically create html elements using pure JavaScript.  The elements are there but we get an error running and we want to be able to go back and use/grab those elements later.  Any advice on what we are doing wrong would be much appreciated.

**The HTML:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>JavaScript Grid</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="grid"></div>

    <script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**The js:**

```
(function() {

    var grid = document.getElementById("grid");

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var temp = document.createElement("DIV");
        temp.className = "row";
        grid.appendChild(temp);
    }

    var row = grid.getElementsByClassName("row");

})();
```

**The CSS:**

```
.grid {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: black;
}

.row {
    overflow: auto;
}

.box {
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: white;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Where/what is the error?

Comment: You and your friend should read this: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

Comment: Thanks.  Yeah we are using the dev tools but we horribly new to js.  We get an error 
Uncaught  ReferenceError: row is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

I see no error on your code. 
your divs are collected and you can play with them around. take a look to the jsfiddle and open your console. (press F12 or inspect element on right mouse click).

```
    (function() {

    var grid = document.getElementById("grid");

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var temp = document.createElement("DIV");
        temp.className = "row";
        grid.appendChild(temp);
    }

    var row = grid.getElementsByClassName("row");

    row[row.length - 1].style.borderColor = "blue";
    row[0].style.borderColor = "red";
})();
```

and the css

```
.row {
    background.color:#f2f2f2;
    border: 1px solid #dadada;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    height:20px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hu7a7k0s/